# View Google Drive API fro personal website

Tags: google-drive-api

I am making a website and I was wondering if I could keep a small view of the Google Drive API on my website. In other words, I want people to be able to view the things they have in their Google Drive API. I want it to look kind of how you would embed Google Maps using the Google Maps API. If I can, I would love it if you guys send a link to where I can learn how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to start with [Google Drive REST API Overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) to fully understand what you can do using Google Drive API. Then from there, you may try the given quickstarts depending on the platform that you're using and explore other links that you may find in the given documentation. I would suggest that you check [about authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth) since every request your application sends to the Drive API must include an authorization token.

Comment: @Teyam Hi Teyam, thank you for the advice I read the Google Drive REST API and I think I found out a way to make sure my plan works. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely look into the [REST API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) from Google. you do need a [token for authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in), so do look into that.

Good Luck!